# How to create a Sankey in icCube?

Tags: sankey-diagram, iccube, iccube-reporting

I tried to create a Sankey diagram using icCube reporting but everything I try is not working...

I did not find any sankey example in icCube [demo](http://www.iccube.com/livedemo/)...
No more on the icCube [documentation](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/viz/viz/doc/viz20GoogleVisualizationCharts.php)...

Can someone provide a working example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working example [here](http://www.inside-vision.com/iccube/inzicht-op-de-werkvloer/).
Created for a customer that wanted to see the Bill of Material explosion.

This demo is based on a custom sankey widget from D3.

Comment: Thxs @arthur, is this custom widget something you could share ?

Comment: No problem, just drop me an e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

In [demo3](http://demo3.iccube.com/icCube/doc/ic3report#) now you can find an example (Shared / Other / Sankey).

The username and password is demo / demo.

Comment: Txs Istvan... Just tried Shared / Other / Sankey... But I get error `d3.sankey is not a function`.